# QuickSight disable future dates greater than current date in Date Picker

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have a requirement to disallow selecting future dates in Date picker in QuickSight. Want to know if any one came across this scenario

Eg : If today is 13th Dec 2021 I want date picker to disable all dates greater than 13th Dec 2021 from selection

Comment: Is this in a dashboard or an analysis?

Comment: For both, I want to do it analysis and publish it to dashboard